# Transfer image source from parent component to child component vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I used a variable to store the file name of the image inside a parent component, and then I used props to transfer it to the child component. However, the child element is not rendering the image.

Parent component data:

```
first_day: [
    {
      class: "card1",
      time: "1:00",
      talk: "1 Name of talk",
      description: "1 Talk description will be here Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s...",
      speaker: "first last",
      pic_url: "logo.png"
    }
]
```

Child component html:

```
<img v-bind:src="'../assets/' + pic_url">
```

Child component props:

```
props: {
    click: Number,
    speaker: String,
    description: String,
    talk: String,
    pic_url: String,
    time: String
}
```

File structure:

```
project folder
    -src
        -assets
            -logo.png
        -components
            -child component (.vue)
        -parent component (.vue)
```

The image is in assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using require function like

```
<img v-bind:src="require(`@/assets/${pic_url}`)">
```

OR

```
<img v-bind:src="require(`../assets/${pic_url}`)">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Troubleshoot if the props is reaching the child component first, e.g. try to console log them first
- Then try to use computed properties to generate the source link

  ```
  computed: {imgsrc: `.../assets/${this.pic_url}`}
  ```
- then just call the computed property in your template

  ```
  <img :src="imgsrc">
  ```

Comment: Thanks I was also able to use computed